# Trying to install subl in the terminal on my mac to allow me to add files to sublime from the terminal

Tags: terminal

I am trying to install subl in the terminal on my mac to allow me to add files to sublime from the terminal.

I have entered the following line to my terminal.

> ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime ln: /usr/local/bin/sublime

When I do that I get a message like this telling me that permission is denied.

> ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
>   ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: Permission denied

How am I able to fix or get around this?

Comment: Have you tried prefixing `sudo`?

Comment: thank you, I forgot about sudo :-)

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "Permission Denied" often means that you do not have execute permission on the file.

Try prefixing `sudo` like this:
`sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime ln: /usr/local/bin/sublime`